# Android spinner scroll styling issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this spinner:

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/country_code_spinner"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I use this layout for the items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/country_code_spinner_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/country_code_spinner_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/country_code_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_country_code_icon"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_code_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/country_code_spinner_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

@drawable/country_code_spinner_background looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/corporate_green"
        android:state_activated="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/telephone_number_background" />
</selector>
```

The result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a48c.jpg

As you can see, the background of items looks fine until the point where the scrollbar starts. This looks even worse when one of the items is longer than the rest (such as Finland). Any ideas how I can make the background color of the scrollbar match the regular background of the spinner items? And solve the variable width issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout **width="match_parent** solve that your problem ..try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/country_code_spinner_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/country_code_spinner_background"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/country_code_icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_country_code_icon"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/country_code_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/country_code_spinner_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `<LinearLayout>` change the width to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

This will allow your item fully fill the width of the spinner.